# SaxParseException when trying to set security="none" in URL interceptor

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to ignore security checking (it gets its own encryption setting) on one of the URLs within current Spring application, by using

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/notimportant/url**" security="none" />
```

but I get

```
nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc
-complex-type.3.2.2: Attribute 'security' is not allowed to appear in element 
'sec:intercept-url'.
```

Here is the namespace setting:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:sec="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
                    http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.1.xsd">
```

So how can I avoid authentication for that url exactly

Comment: that's because `security` is not a valid attribute for `intercept-url`. try with `access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"`

Comment: @guido IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY resolve the error :) thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `filters="none"` instead of `security="none"`.

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/notimportant/url**" filters="none" />
```

This is deprecated in Spring 3.1, though, so you can try this

```
<sec:http pattern="/notimportant/url**" security="none"/>
```

Check out [the documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.x/reference/springsecurity-single.html#ns-form-and-basic) for more details.

Comment: thanks but `filters="none"` doesn't work, giving me Configuration problem: The use of "filters='none'" is no longer supported. Please define a separate <http> element for the pattern you want to exclude and use the attribute "security='none'".

Comment: @Dreamer Yes, I added that in my edited answer. Does that work?

Comment: no errors and now there are two <sec:http> elements, one for non security and one for intercept urls, but the application is still request login page for that url...may be that's another topic?

Comment: Two `<sec:http>` elements shouldn't be a problem themselves (check the examples from the documentation I linked in the answer). Maybe the rules in them are conflicting, you could post them in your question. Did you try the suggestion from @guido 's comment? It may be a quick solution for you if it works.

Comment: guido's solution resolve the error too. I think it is not fair to keep stacking questions as you have already resolved this topic. I should close this question and will open new thread about new questions. Thanks for the timely answer ! :)

Comment: I have open another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999995/how-to-allow-web-service-request-by-pass-spring-authentication please give a hint if get any ideas, thanks !

Answer (score 1):

That's because `security` is not a valid attribute for element `intercept-url`. Try with `access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"`, like this:

```
<sec:intercept-url pattern="/notimportant/url**" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
```

Comment: Thank you I have pop up another question regarding similar issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26999995/how-to-allow-web-service-request-by-pass-spring-authentication, could you please give a hint?